# Angular 2 - ngClass with object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have coded something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of boxesArr.status | orderby : {key: 'order'}; let i = index;
             [ngClass]="boxes['statusBox' + i]" [ngStyle]="{'flex-basis': item.size + '%'}">
```

For [ngClass] I add dynamic object property. This code works fine with one variable. But I need to use other variables in [ngClass] instead [ngStyle]. I tried this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of boxesArr.status | orderby : {key: 'order'}; let i = index;"
             [ngClass]="{boxes['statusBox' + i]: true, newClass: newVar}">
```

Unfortunately this code is not working.

Comment: newClass is string or object property?

Comment: It is string type

Comment: can you try this  [ngClass]="{boxes['statusBox' + i]: true, 'newClass': newVar}"

Comment: [ngClass]="{boxes['statusBox' + i]: true, 'newClass': newVar}" not working